# Using filter for all but last value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am using the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function in JavaScript to get data from a JSON object. I want all but the final entry. How do I do that? (for e.g. in the for...loop I can do array.length-1 to avoid the final value)

The goal is to get all values for Environmental Areas as so except for the last value:

```
Air pollution and emissions: 27
Drilling and extraction: 19
Infrastructure and planning: 13
Animals: 12
Water pollution: 11
Toxic substances and safety: 8
Other: 10 // I do not want this value
```

I have written this function below to get all the values regarding Environmental Areas.

```
let x = summary.map(function (item) {
  return item['Environmental Areas'] + ': ' + item.Total + '<br />';
});
 
The JSON array of objects is -

var summary = [
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Air pollution and emissions',
    Completed: '19',
    'In progress': '8',
    Total: '27',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Drilling and extraction',
    Completed: '11',
    'In progress': '8',
    Total: '19',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Infrastructure and planning',
    Completed: '12',
    'In progress': '1',
    Total: '13',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Animals',
    Completed: '11',
    'In progress': '1',
    Total: '12',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Water pollution',
    Completed: '4',
    'In progress': '7',
    Total: '11',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Toxic substances and safety',
    Completed: '6',
    'In progress': '2',
    Total: '8',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'Other',
    Completed: '5',
    'In progress': '5',
    Total: '10',
  },
  {
    'Environmental Areas': 'All',
    Completed: '68',
    'In progress': '32',
    Total: '100',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to remove the literal last item, this will work:

```js
// Remove the last item, literally, before mapping:
let x = summary.slice(0,-1).map(function (item) {
  return item['Environmental Areas'] + ': ' + item.Total + '<br />';
});

console.log(x)
```

This is not a very robust solution though. Will the JSON ever come back in a
different order? Will data be added or removed some day?

**A better approach is think about *why* we're removing the last item and code
for that case.** If the reason for removing the last item is Environmental Area
`'All'`, then check for that explicitly:

```js
let y = summary
  // Remove the item for 'All' Environmental Areas
  .filter((item) => item['Environmental Areas'] !== 'All')
  // Now map over the filtered results to generate markup
  .map((item) => item['Environmental Areas'] + ': ' + item.Total + '<br />')

console.log(y)
```

Now the logic will not break down if the order of the JSON payload changes. It
is based on the semantics of the data, not the logistical details like order.

You could also use `Array.reduce` to do everything together:

```js
let z = summary.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  const area = item['Environmental Areas']
  if (area !== 'All') {
    accumulator.push(`${area}: ${item.Total}<br />`)
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])

console.log(z)
```

These three snippets all return the same result:

```
// x
[
  'Air pollution and emissions: 27<br />',
  'Drilling and extraction: 19<br />',
  'Infrastructure and planning: 13<br />',
  'Animals: 12<br />',
  'Water pollution: 11<br />',
  'Toxic substances and safety: 8<br />',
  'Other: 10<br />'
]

// y
[
  'Air pollution and emissions: 27<br />',
  'Drilling and extraction: 19<br />',
  'Infrastructure and planning: 13<br />',
  'Animals: 12<br />',
  'Water pollution: 11<br />',
  'Toxic substances and safety: 8<br />',
  'Other: 10<br />'
]

// z
[
  'Air pollution and emissions: 27<br />',
  'Drilling and extraction: 19<br />',
  'Infrastructure and planning: 13<br />',
  'Animals: 12<br />',
  'Water pollution: 11<br />',
  'Toxic substances and safety: 8<br />',
  'Other: 10<br />'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can copy the array, then remove the last one?
You can do so using the spread operator and splice, like this:

```javascript
var mySummary = [ ...summary ]; // Copy the array. Note: This is an ES6 feature.
mySummary.splice(-1, 1); // Remove the last element
```

Then you just use map on mySummary instead (or any name you want for that. You can also use the original array if you can afford losing the final entry, then you can just skip the first line and use `summary.splice`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this

```
let x = summary.filter((_,index) => index != summary.length - 1 ).map(function (item) {
  return item['Environmental Areas'] + ': ' + item.Total + '<br />';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that U have a object

```
let objs = [{
 'Air pollution and emissions': 27,
 'Drilling and extraction': 19,
 'Infrastructure and planning': 13,
 'Animals': 12,
 'Water pollution': 11,
 'Toxic substances and safety': 8,
 'Other': 10,
```

}]

If u don't need 'Other' property， try this way

```
let newObjs = objs.map(obj => {
 const {Other, ...newObj} = obj
 return newObj
})
```

The result will give the same obj without Other property

Answer (score 1):

you mean that ?

```js
const summary = 
      [ { 'Environmental Areas': 'Air pollution and emissions', Completed: '19', 'In progress':  '8', Total:  '27' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'Drilling and extraction',     Completed: '11', 'In progress':  '8', Total:  '19' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'Infrastructure and planning', Completed: '12', 'In progress':  '1', Total:  '13' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'Animals',                     Completed: '11', 'In progress':  '1', Total:  '12' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'Water pollution',             Completed:  '4', 'In progress':  '7', Total:  '11' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'Toxic substances and safety', Completed:  '6', 'In progress':  '2', Total:   '8' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'Other',                       Completed:  '5', 'In progress':  '5', Total:  '10' } 
      , { 'Environmental Areas': 'All',                         Completed: '68', 'In progress': '32', Total: '100' } 
      ] 

const result = Object.fromEntries(
                  summary.filter(x=>x['Environmental Areas']!='Other' && x['Environmental Areas']!='All')
                        . map(e=>[e['Environmental Areas'], e.Total]))

console.log( result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just restrict it to all values apart the last one in the reduce function. When you reach the last element, do nothing.

```
let x = summary.reduce(function(acc, item, i) {
  if (i === summary.length - 1) return acc;
  return acc.push(item['Environmental Areas'] + ': ' + item.Total + '<br />')
  return acc;
}, []);
```